# Android: How could I add paid skins to my app?

Tags: android, skinning

I want to make some "skins" for my Android app, and sell them on the Android market so that when the user downloads the paid skin, it becomes available in my app, perhaps in settings. I'm just not sure how this is done. If anyone could lead me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Comment: This is not a full answer, but it seems PayPal has developed something that may help: http://www.mobilecrunch.com/2010/05/19/paypal-launches-in-app-payment-library-for-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and can be done.

You can find working examples in OI Notepad and OI Shopping list apps (apps are free, advanced themes are paid). The whole concept is introduced [here](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/348) and the source code is available [here](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/downloads/detail?name=BasicColorsTheme-source-1.0.0.zip&can=2&q=).

Credits goes to [OpenIntents](http://www.openintents.org/en/).